# Find and replace HTML accross multiple files

Tags: html, replace, batch-processing

I'm working on cleaning up and implementing a custom built content management system for a website.  All pages on the website are simple, and essentially static, HTML pages built as a simple template that is something like the following:

```
<html>
    <head><!-- resources, scripts, etc. --></head>

    <body>

       <div id="page">

           <div id="header"><!--- static --></div>

           <div id="content">
                <!-- The main content - different on every page -->
           </div>

           <div>
             <!-- Side bar -- footer-- and other static persistent content -->
           </div>

       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is batch find and replace the `#content` element with a variable or a comment or nothing at all.  I've already extracted the content and stored it in a file in the same directory as the corresponding HTML files.

I can see two basic pathways to accomplish what I want:

1. Replace the `#content` in all the files with what I want.
2. Extract the html from the pages and either pre or post process the data to remove the `#content` element, and then write the modified html to a new file.

**Note**:*There are too many files to do this one by one.*

I've experimented with different methods to do this, including a jQuery plugin, various nodejs solutions, grepWin, and [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html).  Xidel was the most useful, but I've not figured out how to use it to output all the HTML minus the `#content`.

Ideally, I'd like to do with the simplicity of `$.replaceWith`, i.e.:

```
$('#content').replaceWith('...');
```

Of course, if it was that simple, I probably would've stumbled across it by now.

Does anyone know a tool or a solution for this? - even if it is within a code editor that offers find and replace in files functionality.  This only has to be done once, so it doesn't need to be programmatic.

**Edit**:*This is an example of the desired before and and after scenario.*

**Before**

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        I am content in the head - I should remain as I am
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="page"><!-- Wrapper for all pages -->
           <div id="header">
               I am a static header - I should remain as I am
           </div>
           <div id="content">
                I am content - I am different on every page.  I would like to be replaced please.
          </div>
          <div>
              I am things like a sidebar, footer, copyright logo.
              I may or may not be wrapped in a div, but I don't need to be changed
          </div>
       </div><!-- End of wrapper -->
    </body>
 </html>
```

---

### **After**

```
<html>
    <head>
        I am content in the head - I should remain as I am (see I haven't changed)
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="page"><!-- Wrapper for all pages -->
           <div id="header">
               I am a static header - I should remain as I am (I haven't changed either)
           </div>
           <div id="content">
                I AM VERY DIFFERENT.  The only Thing inside of me is a variable. :)
          </div>
          <div>
              I am things like a sidebar, footer, copyright logo.
              I may or may not be wrapped in a div, but I don't need to be changed
              (Nope.  I haven't changed either)
          </div>
       </div><!-- End of wrapper -->
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Show an example of before and after.  It's not clear if you want multiple line replacement or simple text, and the scope of the change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by replacing it with `@content` unless that is just supposed to be text, but any DOM parser can do this job very easily.  If you can run one through the command line it will work great, but it's also easy to do in a browser like Chrome.

Open the HTML document with Chrome and open the console (f12).  Run

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
content.parentNode.removeChild(content);
```

Now you can right click and "copy as HTML" on the root `<html>` node in Elements, or even print the HTML in the console with `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: I will edit my question to clarify, but there are way too many files to do this one by one.

Comment: Also it's way easier than that.  I could just use chrome console and (since I am using jquery), just do:  `$('html').find('#content').detach();copy($('html')[0].outerHTML);`

Comment: @user1167442 is this saving back to the file

Answer (score 0):

Use notepad ++,

Open all the pages you want to edit, 
run a finder and go to replace section and hit replace in all opened pages.

I guess this will help with batch replacing.